# HTML table duplicates content on each submit click

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

[image]

My program takes **.csv** file, reads information from it and sends it to HTML table in js.
In addition I have input field for future actions. It's made to search data throughout the table by the filter from input.

**The problem** is that if table is already generated, and I click on Submit again, my table appears again creating copies (as showed on picture)

[image]

**The question** is how to make it not to make its copies on submit

**.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Excel Transform Site</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./excel-transfrom.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="input-form">
         <input type="file" id="file-choose" apply=".csv">

         <label class="test-input-label">Test Input</label>
         <input type="text" id="test-input">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button">
      </form><br>

      <table id="data-table"></table>

      <script src="./excel-transform.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**.js:**

```js
const inputForm = document.getElementById("input-form")
const file = document.getElementById("file-choose")
const filterInput = document.getElementById("test-input")

let table = document.createElement("table")
let thead = document.createElement("thead")
let tbody = document.createElement("tbody")

function csvToArray(str, delimiter=',') {
   const headers = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(delimiter)
   const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).split("\n")

   headers.pop()

   const arr = rows.map((row) => {
      const values = row.split(delimiter)
      const element = headers.reduce((object, header, index) => {
         object[header] = values[index]
         return object
      }, {})
      return element
   })

   return arr
}

inputForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()

   const input = file.files[0]
   const reader = new FileReader()

   reader.onload = function(e) {
      const text = e.target.result
      const data = csvToArray(text)
      
      table.appendChild(thead)
      table.appendChild(tbody)

      document.getElementById('data-table').appendChild(table)
      
      let hrow = document.createElement('tr')
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data[0]).length; i++) {
         let theader = document.createElement('th')

         theader.innerHTML = Object.keys(data[0])[i]
         hrow.appendChild(theader)
      }
      thead.appendChild(hrow)

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         let drow = document.createElement('tr')
         console.log(data[i])
         for (let j = 0; j < Object.values(data[i]).length; j++) {
            let tdata = document.createElement('td')

            tdata.innerHTML = Object.values(data[i])[j]

            drow.appendChild(tdata)
         }
         tbody.appendChild(drow)
      }
   }

   reader.readAsText(input)
})
```

Comment: [`replaceChildren`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) might come in handy.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it seems to be an answer, but can you please explain how to use this method in my case

Answer (score 1):

**Solution is already found**

In the comment section `replaceChildren` method has been suggested, but I decided to use 
`.innerHTML = ''` instead

So, when submit event is happening, table content erases with `innerHTML = ''` if exists

Here is how js code looks now:

```js
const inputForm = document.getElementById("input-form")
const file = document.getElementById("file-choose")
const filterInput = document.getElementById("test-input")

let table = document.createElement("table")
let thead = document.createElement("thead")
let tbody = document.createElement("tbody")

function csvToArray(str, delimiter=',') {
   const headers = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(delimiter)
   const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).split("\n")

   headers.pop()

   const arr = rows.map((row) => {
      const values = row.split(delimiter)
      const element = headers.reduce((object, header, index) => {
         object[header] = values[index]
         return object
      }, {})
      return element
   })

   return arr
}

inputForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()

\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
   table.innerHTML = ''
   thead.innerHTML = ''
   tbody.innerHTML = ''
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

   const input = file.files[0]
   const reader = new FileReader()

   reader.onload = function(e) {
      const text = e.target.result
      const data = csvToArray(text)
      
      table.appendChild(thead)
      table.appendChild(tbody)

      document.getElementById('data-table').appendChild(table)
      
      let hrow = document.createElement('tr')
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data[0]).length; i++) {
         let theader = document.createElement('th')

         theader.innerHTML = Object.keys(data[0])[i]
         hrow.appendChild(theader)
      }
      thead.appendChild(hrow)

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         let drow = document.createElement('tr')
         console.log(data[i])
         for (let j = 0; j < Object.values(data[i]).length; j++) {
            let tdata = document.createElement('td')

            tdata.innerHTML = Object.values(data[i])[j]

            drow.appendChild(tdata)
         }
         tbody.appendChild(drow)
      }
   }

   reader.readAsText(input)
})
```